# How to use ReactiveCocoa for UITextViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to make my `UITextView` to be not editable when the length of text is more than 200.  When using `UITextViewDelegate`, I can use `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`. How to make it using ReactiveCocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no good way to "lift" a protocol method that returns a value, since it'd require that the signal is synchronous. Could you disable the text view instead?

Comment: I have resolved this problem by setting the delegate before using `signal_text` and using `textViewShouldChangeXXX` instead. Thank you after all.